# Get all images attached to any post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting a list of all the images the following way:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type'       => 'attachment',
  'post_mime_type'  => 'image',
  'post_status'     => 'inherit',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
 ) );
```

But I'm trying to get only those who are uploaded to a post on my website.

Not images attached to a specific post but exclude those who aren't featured on any post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is paste the following code inside a loop.

```
$args = array(
        'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(), // your post id
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'numberposts'    => -1, // show all
        'post_status'    => 'any',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
        'order'           => 'ASC'
   );

$images = get_posts($args);
if($images) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID); ?>" />
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Actually, it seems some images are being left out without any reason

Comment: @Archipel can you please `print_r($images)` and check it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the post_mime_type is not correct.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'attachment',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image/gif',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Hope this helps!